# The method forEach(Consumer<? super Map<String,Object>>) in the type Iterable<Map<String,Object>> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> k

Tags: java-8

Using Java 8 and getting the below error. I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, `Map<String, Object>` contains `ACC_NO` and `true` or `ACC_NO` and `false`.

Have the Map like this:

```
[{14125=false}, {1210=false}, {13118=false}, {10607=false}, {4973=false}, {12175=false}..............,
```

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method accept(Map)
>       - The method forEach(Consumer>) in the type Iterable> is not applicable for the arguments (( k,  
>        v) -> {})

I need to simply create another map out of it to used

```
// If value is false, I need to add that again
List<Map<String, Object>> excludeAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        detailsOfPans.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("Item : " + k + " Count : " + v);
            Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
            if(!v) {
                excludePANs.add(myMap.put(k, v));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently only iterating over the outer list instead of the maps which form the items of the list. To solve this, you would use

```
detailsOfPans.forEach(map -> map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    // Do something with k, v
}));
```